# How to divide down to decimals and not get zero in Java?

Tags: java, division

```
double[] arrayName = new double[10]; 
arrayName[0] = (14/49)*100;
```

Trying to get percentage of two numbers, 14 / 49, and add results to an array. All it returns is 0.0. Same thing if I use float instead of double. New to Java.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either cast the `int`s to `double`, or just use `double`s.

For example:

```
double[] arrayName = new double[10]; 
resultValue[0] = (14.0/49.0)*100;
```

or:

```
double[] arrayName = new double[10]; 
resultValue[0] = ((double)14/49)*100;
```

Comment: Not working for some reason. Here's what I have:
  double[] arrayName = new double[10];
    arrayName[0] = (double)(14/49)*100;
   System.out.println("Result: "+arrayName[0]);' Returns 0.0. Sorry about formatting in this comment

Comment: Working, thanks @mmnumbp! But I had to do it as '((double)14/(double)49)*100;' The first method didn't work.

Comment: Ah sorry, I placed (double) in the wrong spot. Here, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @batoutofhell: you can use backticks to format code inline in comments.

Answer (score 10):

How you see it:

```
(double/double)*double
```

How the JVM sees it

```
(int/int)*int
```

From the the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).  int to double is a widening conversion.  From [§5.1.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2):

> Widening primitive conversions do not
>   lose information about the overall
>   magnitude of a numeric value.
>
> [...]
>
> Conversion of an int or a long value
>   to float, or of a long value to
>   double, may result in loss of
>   precision-that is, the result may lose
>   some of the least significant bits of
>   the value. In this case, the resulting
>   floating-point value will be a
>   correctly rounded version of the
>   integer value, using IEEE 754
>   round-to-nearest mode [(§4.2.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#9249).

If you replace one of those with a double literal (like adding `.0` or cast one of them to `double` and you should get the result you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
arrayName[0] = (14/49)*100.0; // put ".0" after any of the numbers
```

or this:

```
arrayName[0] = (double)(14/49)*100;
```

Answer (score 3):

At least one of your values should be a `double`:

```
double[] arrayName = new double[10]; 
arrayName[0] = (14d/49d)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = (14d/49)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = (14/49d)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = (14.0/49)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = (14/49.0)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = (14/(double)49)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = ((double)14/49)*100;
// or...
// arrayName[0] = ((double)14/(double)49)*100;
```

Answer (score 2):

As many others have pointed, you just have to set the constants as doubles:

```
arrayName[0] = (14*100)/49.0;
```

This way, you convert only the last computation to double instead of the beginning , and reduce the number of floating point calculations.

Btw, if you wish, you can also have the result as an integer by using the same method of swapping the order and use multiplication before division, for example: 14*100/49 instead of  (14/49)*100.